# I am getting these errors while deploying my project on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

`TypeError: fetch failed at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11372:11) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) at async global This fetch (/Versel/path0/.next/server/chunks/638.js:1:36426) at async _ (/Versel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:1:157951) at async I (/Versel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:1:158482) { cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 at TCP Connect Wrap after Connect [as on complete] (node:net:1555:16) at TCP Connect Wrap callback Trampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) { error no: -111, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', sys call: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 3000`your text `}`your text`
}
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11372:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async globalThis.fetch (/Versel/path0/.next/server/chunks/638.js:1:36426)
at async _ (/Versel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:1:157951)
at async I (/Versel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:1:158482) {
cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
err no: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 3000
}
}
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11372:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async globalThis.fetch (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/638.js:1:36426)
at async _ (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:1:157951)
at async I (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:1:158482)

```
# [.env file code[fetching api[sanity studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKxxw.png)]       (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqlAV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB0hE.png)
```

i am using the sanity for content management system and typescript for static typing.`

Comment: Did you read the error? It includes a link to a help page. Always read the error and make an attempt to understand it, don't ignore it like you are now! When your pre-rendering is happening, it's trying to load data from localhost:3000. What do you expect to be running there?

Comment: Fetch failed. Cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000. Should be pretty clear.